# problems starting mysql server docker container - won't go past "Initializing database"

Tags: mysql, docker

I've downloaded to docker container mysql/mysql-server:5.7 and when I tried to start the container, mysql server won't start. The log files don't tell me much information either. Tried searching a solution but couldn't find any.

I tried simple "docker start" command to using environment variables required for mysql server but none worked

```
root@samsan:~/docker# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@samsan:~/docker# 

root@samsan:~/docker# docker run --name db mysql/mysql-server:5.7
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.26-1.1.11
[Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.
[Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.
[Entrypoint] Initializing database
root@samsan:~/docker# 
root@samsan:~/docker# 
root@samsan:~/docker# 
root@samsan:~/docker# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@samsan:~/docker# 


root@samsan:~/docker# docker logs db
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.26-1.1.11
[Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.
[Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.
[Entrypoint] Initializing database
root@samsan:~/docker#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `docker cp db:/var/log/mysqld.log -` to see `mysqld`'s log - maybe that will show what the problem is.

Although, I could not reproduce what you are encountering:

```
$ docker run   --name db mysql/mysql-server:5.7

[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.26-1.1.11
[Entrypoint] No password option specified for new database.
[Entrypoint]   A random onetime password will be generated.
[Entrypoint] Initializing database
[Entrypoint] Database initialized
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
[Entrypoint] GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: 0h@ziGqAracLyPEqk@GkOd$YKg@

[Entrypoint] ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

[Entrypoint] Server shut down
[Entrypoint] Setting root user as expired. Password will need to be changed before database can be used.

[Entrypoint] MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.26-1.1.11
```

... in a different terminal session:

```
$ docker exec -it db mysqladmin --defaults-extra-file=/healthcheck.cnf ping

mysqld is alive
```

```
$ docker cp db:/var/log/mysqld.log - | tail -n 3

2019-05-10T18:51:08.472164Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.26'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: thanks for the support... the log file actually doesn't show anything.. `root@samsan:~# docker cp db:/var/log/mysqld.log - | tail -n 3
mysqld.log0100640000003300000330000000000013465432655011274 0ustar0000000000000000root@samsan:~#`... this shouldn't  be a problem with docker since I have Jenkins image running fine.

Comment: Also I ran failed container in Debian environment. but when I tried with my MacBook, same image working as expected. What areas should I be looking at to troubleshoot to this problem.